# Forward navigation with Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to know if anyone knows a way to achieve both forward and backward navigation with Fragments?

I would like to start with a single Fragment, when I press the next button a new Fragment must be created, when I push the back button, the previous Fragment must be shown. My code does this and it saves any changes I have made to any previous Fragments as they are saved in the back stack, however, I want the same to be true of forward navigation, is there any way in which I can achieve this?

So to be more exact, I want to for example create 10 Fragments all with a single text box in which I can enter some data, each time I enter data and press the next button it must navigate to the next Fragment, have an empty text box and save the previous Fragment plus data entered to the back stack (this it currently does). So when I get to Fragment 10, I want to be able to go back to Fragment 1 and then back to Fragment 10 but as I navigate forward again, the data I originally entered must still be there. Then when I navigate to Fragment 11 it must be an empty text box. So it must be a forward and backward navigation system of sorts.

The code below generates Fragments dynamically from code and adds Views to it dynamically as well (at run time). This is the code I currently have working for going backwards.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    int mStackLevel = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button IntegratedBiometricsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.integrated_biometrics_button);
        IntegratedBiometricsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent IBIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SimpleScanActivity.class);
                startActivity(IBIntent);
            }
        });

        // Watch for button clicks.
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_fragment);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                addFragmentToStack();
            }
        });
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_fragment);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                if(mStackLevel > 0){mStackLevel--;}
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            // Do first time initialization -- add initial fragment.
            Fragment newFragment = CountingFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment).commit();
        } else
        {
            mStackLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt("level");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("level", mStackLevel);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    void addFragmentToStack()
    {
        mStackLevel++;

        // Instantiate a new fragment.
        Fragment newFragment = CountingFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);

        // Add the fragment to the activity, pushing this transaction
        // on to the back stack.
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.simple_fragment, newFragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

    }

    public static class CountingFragment extends Fragment
    {
        int mNum;

        /**
         * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num"
         * as an argument.
         */
        static CountingFragment newInstance(int num)
        {
            CountingFragment f = new CountingFragment();

            // Supply num input as an argument.
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("num", num);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }

        /**
         * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
        }

        /**
         * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
         * instance number.
         */
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            int ID = 0;
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

            LinearLayout fragmentLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.infoLayout);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            TextView tv = new TextView(container.getContext());
            tv.setId(ID);
            ID++;
            tv.setTextSize(16);
            tv.setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
            fragmentLayout.addView(tv);

            EditText et = new EditText(container.getContext());
            et.setId(ID);
            ID++;
            et.setHint("Text");
            et.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            et.setLayoutParams(lp);
            fragmentLayout.addView(et);

            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(container.getContext());
            cb.setId(ID);
            cb.setChecked(false);
            cb.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            cb.setLayoutParams(lp);
            fragmentLayout.addView(cb);

            cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Yo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            ID++;

            ImageView iv = new ImageView(container.getContext());
            iv.setId(ID);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.output);
            iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
            fragmentLayout.addView(iv);

            iv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
            {
                public boolean onLongClick(View v)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "It works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
            ID++;

            //View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            //((TextView) tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
            //tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.gallery_thumb));
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want a wizard UI, why not use [one of](https://github.com/DWorkS/AWizard) the [many existing](https://github.com/DWorkS/AWizard) open source [wizard libraries](https://github.com/TechFreak/WizardPager), rather than rolling your own?

Comment: @CommonsWare you are the first person to actually point me in the right direction, been trying to figure this out for a while now. However, how would I go about adding custom content to this like I am doing in the onCreateView method of my code above?

Comment: You would follow the instructions for the library that you chose.